Integral points on "complex exponential surface" in $\mathbb{C}^3$
I encountered the following object in $\mathbb{C}^3$ defined for $m\in\mathbb{N}$ by
$$A_m:=\lbrace (z_1,z_2,z_3)\in\mathbb{C}^3|(2^{2z_3}m-1)2^{2z_1+z_2+1}+3^{z_2-1}(2^{2z_1}-2^2-3^{z_3+1}m)=0\rbrace$$
for which I need to find integer points $(n_1^{(m)},n_2^{(m)},n_3^{(m)})\in A_m\cap\mathbb{N}^3$.
Assuming that I have found such points $(n_1^{(m)},n_2^{(m)},n_3^{(m)})$ and using the simple fact that $3=1+2$ I obtain that the defining function $f_m$ of $A_m$ consists only of powers of $2$ in this case, given by
$$f_m(n_1^{(m)},n_2^{(m)},n_3^{(m)})=(2^{2n_3^{(m)}}m-1)2^{2n_1^{(m)}+n_2^{(m)}+1}+\sum_{j}\binom{n_2^{(m)}-1}{j}2^{j}\left(2^{2n_1^{(m)}}-2^2-\sum_{i}\binom{n_3^{(m)}+1}{i}2^{j}m\right)$$
by the binomial theorem. Unfortunately, here I get stuck trying to reformulate this as a useful polynomial for the general case.
I tried to reformulate $(2^{2z_3}m-1)2^{2z_1+z_2+1}+3^{z_2-1}(2^{2z_1}-2^2-3^{z_3+1}m)$ as a polynomial to get into the realm of algebraic geometry, which can be done in $\mathbb{C}^5$ by setting $x_1=2^{z_1},x_2=2^{z_2},x_3=2^{z_3}$ and $y_1=3^{z_2-1},y_2=3^{z_3-1}$ to obtain
$$p_m(x_1,x_2,x_3,y_1,y_2)=2(x_3^{2}m-1)x_1^{2}x_2+y_1(x_1^2-2^2-9y_2m).$$
This looks somewhat more managable as a polynomial but the points $(n_1^{(m)},n_2^{(m)},n_3^{(m)})$ which I was looking for initially now become logarithms of the corresponding coordinates $n_i^{(m)}=\log_2(x_i)$. This somehow reminds me of valuations and tropical geometry but I am not sure how to proceed. Could anyone give me an indication on how to approach this problem?
Trying to define a ring of powers in parallel to a polynomial ring, using the construction of a polynomial ring over $R[X]$ some commutative ring $R$ considering $X$ as an additional element in $R$, I arrived at a construction using an exponential ring $(R_e,E)$, which allows to build exponentials in $(R_e,E)[X]$ (my handwavy notation) of the form $E(p(X))$, where $p$ is polynomial in $R_e[X]$. My problem, they all have the same "base" and a naive change of base to some element in $a\in R_e$ to obtain "$a^{X}$" would look like $E(XE^{-1}(a))$. My goal is to find a ring which captures the above structure and then investigating the ideal $\langle f_m(Z_1,Z_2,Z_3)\rangle$. Are there any concepts in that regard? I touches exponential Diophantine equations and I have not found much lierature on that.
